# Cómo usar bootstrap 4 con Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, bootstrap-4

quería usar Bootstrap con wordpress y no consigo que los archivos de js funcionen correctamente. ¿Alguien que me pueda ayudar por favor?. Los llamo localmente desde functions.php así:

```
function theme_styles(){

    wp_register_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', array(), '4.0.0', true );
    wp_register_script('scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/scripts.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap');
    wp_enqueue_script('scripts');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles');
```

Haciéndolo así me da el siguiente error de consola:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at bootstrap.bundle.min.js?ver=4.0.0:6
    at bootstrap.bundle.min.js?ver=4.0.0:6
    at bootstrap.bundle.min.js?ver=4.0.0:6
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.bundle.min.js?ver=4.0.0:6
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.bundle.min.js?ver=4.0.0:6
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.bundle.min.js?ver=4.0.0:6
```

Y si lo cargo directamente desde el CDN:

```
function theme_styles(){
    wp_register_script('popper', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.12.3', true );
    wp_register_script('bootstrap', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('popper', 'jquery'), '4.0.0', true );
    wp_register_script('scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/scripts.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('popper');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap');
    wp_enqueue_script('scripts');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles');
```

me da el siguiente error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
```

Comment: [Aquí se te explica con lujo de detalles cómo hacerlo](https://ayudawp.com/bootstrap-wordpress/#Como_instalar_Bootstrap_en_WordPress). Compáralo con tu procedimiento.

Comment: Gracias. Ya lo ayer probé sin éxito. Cargando el CDN y/o locamente los archivos. Es un poco deseperante.

Comment: Prueba con Bootstrap 3 o una versión beta inferior a la beta 4 v.2... **[al parecer hay un bug en esa versión](https://github.com/holger1411/understrap/issues/449)**.

Comment: [La discusión en este hilo indica que hay realmente un problema en la v. 4](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/24417) y quizá problemas de compatibilidad. Tu biblioteca jQuery es muy antigua. Uno de los comentarios dice que BS 4 no trabajará con jQuery 1, lo cual no me sorprende... jQuery va por la versión 3, así que la v. 1 tendrá un montón de cosas obsoletas con respecto a BS.

Comment: Gracias si lo he visto.

Answer (score 1):

Carga siempre primero **JQuery** ya que **bootstrap** necesita **javascript** para funcionar.

> (jQuery debe ser lo primero, luego Popper.js, y luego nuestros
>   complementos de JavaScript.)

En la [documentación](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) explica cual es el mejor sitio para colocar los `scripts`

---

Inténtalo sin cargar la libreria [popper](https://popper.js.org/), en el caso de que no vayas a usar estos elementos. Esto lo digo porque yo he tenido porblemas recientemente y con el mismo error en `fn`

---

La carga la haría antes de el cierre de la etiqueta `</body>` para que cargue la página antes que los `scripts`.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Estaría bien si le pudieras explicar por qué. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias. Haciendo lo así tirando del cdn no da error. No obstante lo que necesito son algunos elementos de bootstrap y no todos. Cargándolos individualmente desde el functions o desde el body es desde donde da los errores. Incluso tirando del cdn y usando por ejemplo el carrusel solo no consigo hacerlo funcionar correctamente. O el css va mal o el js.

Comment: Si nos cuentas solo uno de los casos de Error y nos aportas mas documentación acerca de este, a lo mejor podremos ayudarte

Comment: En los casos en los que cargo el JS desde el footer haciendo la llamada al CDN de bootsrap no da error de ningun tipo. En los casos en los que hago la llamada al archivo localmente me sigue dando error. ALguien sabe si lo hna arrelgado ya?